# angularjs directive wait for uib carousel to load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, carousel

I have a directive that loads a uib carousel. In the directive link function, I want to wait in the postlink function until the carousel has finished loading, and then add some event listeners and modify some things. I can't find a way to wait until the carousel has finished loading. The general idea is something like this:

```
scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
            alert(elem[0].querySelector(".left"));
            scope.carouselSpinnerInactive = true;
```

When inside the $viewContentLoaded listener, the alert does not fire. However, when outside of the listener, elem[0].querySelector(".left") is null, I believe because ui.bootstrap hasn't finished creating it. One other option I have considered is waiting for user interaction with the surrounding div, but that is an ugly hack and doesn't work reliably

In addition, I have tried using:

```
 $timeout(function() {
      alert(elem[0].querySelector(".left"));
      scope.carouselSpinnerInactive = true;
 });
```

The alert works properly there, but it turns out that this is also fired well before the carousel actually loads. I know this because carouselSpinnerInactive removes a spinner that takes up the space before the carousel loads, and there is a significant delay between the spinner deactivating and the carousel being visible.